# IOS12 Flip TransitionWith: not working properly

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewanimationtransition, ios12, apple-developer

Developing a heavy duty UI app, I've been reported form the QA team that the "Flip" of our views stopped working properly. Aster testing the issue We noticed that this Issue is only for IOS12.

If you test the code I've added, Even for very simple example with two views with only background color, you will see that in `transitionWith`: the view that is being displayed is not animated, just being hidden. The view that is hidden is being animated correctly.

Again, this is only an issue in IOS12 and works fine in transitionFrom:To:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var firstView: UIView!
    var secondView: UIView!
    var containerView: UIView!

    var showBackView = false

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        //containerView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 32, y: 32, width: 128, height: 128)) - // transitionFrom:To Code

        // General code
        firstView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 32, y: 32, width: 128, height: 128))
        secondView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 32, y: 32, width: 128, height: 128))

        firstView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        secondView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue


        // transitionFrom:To Code
//        containerView.addSubview(firstView)
//        containerView.addSubview(secondView)
//        view.addSubview(containerView)


        // transitionWith: Code
        view.addSubview(firstView)
        view.addSubview(secondView)

        self.firstView.isHidden = false
        self.secondView.isHidden = true

        // General code
        let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 200, y: 200, width: 50, height: 50))
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(tappedButton), for: .touchUpInside)
        button.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
        view.addSubview(button)

    }

    @objc func tappedButton(sender: UIButton!) {
        flip()
    }

    func flip() {
        let transitionOptions: UIView.AnimationOptions = [.transitionFlipFromRight, .showHideTransitionViews]
        // transitionFrom:To Code
//        let toView = showBackView ? firstView : secondView
//        let fromView = showBackView ? secondView : firstView
//        UIView.transition(from: fromView!, to: toView!, duration: 1.0, options: transitionOptions, completion: nil)

        // transitionWith: Code
        print("******************")
        UIView.transition(with: firstView, duration: 3.0, options: transitionOptions, animations: {
            print(self.firstView.isHidden)
            print(self.secondView.isHidden)
            self.firstView.isHidden = !self.firstView.isHidden
        })

        print("----------------------")
        UIView.transition(with: secondView, duration: 3.0, options: transitionOptions, animations: {
            print(self.firstView.isHidden)
            print(self.secondView.isHidden)
            self.secondView.isHidden = !self.secondView.isHidden
        })
    }
}
```

Is this a known issue? I couldn't find any reference for this on the web; unfortunately, this breaks old animations.

Comment: I've solved this issue by using transitionFrom:To:But this is not a solution, This is a workaround. transitionWith: still brakes on IOS12!

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this issue by using transitionFrom:To:But this is not a solution, This is a workaround. transitionWith: still brakes on IOS12!

Comment: you found any solution for this. I am using same code and facing issue in ios15